# How to get Database errors from Unity's Real time database?

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

**Setup**

Unity : 2019.1.6f1
Firebase Version : 6.2.0
Firebase Product : Realtime Database

**My Usage**

```
  internal static DatabaseReference Content()
  {
     return DBReference.Child("content");
  }
```

**Add Data**

```
     CloudSession.Content().Child(_childNode).SetRawJsonValueAsync(_jsonValue).ContinueWith(
        (_task) =>
        {
            if (_task.IsCanceled == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("DB UPLOAD Cancelled -> ");

                if (_task.Exception is System.AggregateException _aggregateException)
                {
                    if (_aggregateException.InnerExceptions[0] is DatabaseException _innerException)
                    {
                        //_innerException.
                    }
                }
            }

            if (_task.IsFaulted == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("DB UPLOAD faulted -> ");
            }

            switch (_task.IsCompleted)
            {
                case true:
                    Debug.Log("New value updated!!! -> " + _childNode);
                    break;
            }
            Debug.Log("--------- DB COMPLETED ---------");
        });
```

**View Data**

```
      CloudSession.Content().Child(_childNode).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(
        (_task) =>
        {
            if (_task.IsCanceled == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("DB RETRIVE Cancelled -> " + _task.Exception);
            }

            if (_task.IsFaulted == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("DB RETRIVE faulted -> " + _task.Exception);
            }

            switch (_task.IsCompleted)
            {
                case true:
                    Debug.Log("JSON value obtained!!!");
                    DataSnapshot _snapshot = _task.Result;

            }
        });
```

**Delete Data**

```
  CloudSession.Content().Child(_childNode).RemoveValueAsync().ContinueWith(
       (_task) =>
       {
           if (_task.IsCanceled == true)
           {
               Debug.Log("DB NODE DELETE Cancelled -> " + _task.Exception);
           }

           if (_task.IsFaulted == true)
           {
               Debug.Log("DB NODE DELETE faulted -> " + _task.Exception);
           }

           switch (_task.IsCompleted)
           {
               case true:
                   Debug.Log("NODE DELETE COMPLETE-> " + _childNode + " -> "+ _task.Status);
                   break;
           }
       });
```

**Request**

- How do I obtain Database error codes when there is a fault at IsCanceled or IsFaulted. I wasn't able to find any relevant examples from github samples repo or documentation.[ 
  [\Firebase Database Error Documentation]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-error)
- Is there any information as to when & how one would receive such errors. The reason behind this is because I never was able to any "Network" error when I disabled internet on the device while performing database operations.

Thank you